# How to link dynamic lib into flutter-desktop in Linux

Tags: flutter-desktop

I am trying to link a third-party dynamic lib in .so file to my flutter-desktop app in Linux, what shall I do. Could some help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: provide concrete commands you run and setup you have in .so and other related files

Comment: As I said, I want to link a third party dynamic lib. I just setup flutter-desktop environment according to the official guild. I have no idea how should I link third-party .so file. @Saskia

Answer (score 0):

The application is built by `linux/CMakeLists.txt`, in the section labeled `# Application build`. You would add your library to that target just as you would for any other CMake build.